# How do I resample the index itself, not the columns, in pandas?

Tags: pandas

I have a data frame like so:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
[
{
  "timestamp" : "2021-03-05 00:00:01", "a" : 1, "b": None,
},
{
  "timestamp" : "2021-03-05 00:00:02", "a" : 2, "b": 100
},
{
  "timestamp" : "2021-03-05 00:02:30", "a" : 3, "b": 200
},
{
  "timestamp" : "2021-03-05 00:03:00", "a" : 4, "b": 300
}]
)
df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df["timestamp"])
df.sort_values(["timestamp"], inplace=True)
df.set_index("timestamp", inplace=True)
```

Producing

```
    a   b
timestamp       
2021-03-05 00:00:01     1   NaN
2021-03-05 00:00:02     2   100.0
2021-03-05 00:02:30     3   200.0
2021-03-05 00:03:00     4   300.0
```

And I want to count how many records occur in each minute.  Importantly, I do not want to count the columns at all.  I just want to count whether there are any values in the row
within the minute.

```
df.resample("T").index.sum().plot()
```

So I try to resample to 1 minute, and then count across the index, and get:

```
AttributeError: 'DatetimeIndexResampler' object has no attribute 'index'
```

What's the right way to count events by interval?

My desired result will be a plot of:

```
2021-03-05 00:00 : 2
2021-03-05 00:01 : 0
2021-03-05 00:02 : 1
2021-03-05 00:03 : 1
```

Comment: I think , you can try `df.resample("T").size()`

Answer (score 0):

try this, you can remove the b column if you please.

```
df = df.drop(columns=['b'])
df = df.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='1min', origin='start_day')).count()    
print(df)


                     a
timestamp             
2021-03-05 00:00:00  2
2021-03-05 00:01:00  0
2021-03-05 00:02:00  1
2021-03-05 00:03:00  1
```

Comment: That's still doing the computations on the b column, right?  For a bigger data set besides this minimal one, with a large number of columns, that can be costly.

Comment: Yes, you could drop the 'b' column from the dataframe by adding this command before regrouping...

```df = df.drop(columns=['b'])```

Comment: Thank you. The non minimal example has hundreds of columns, so I'm looking explicitly to handle this without enumerating columns---just using the index timestamps.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest way to do this is to create a `minute` column and use it to count the observations per group. However, I assume you are dealing with minutes in multiple days, so you can try this slightly longer solution:

```py
# Reset seconds to 00
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index.astype(str).str[:-2] + '00')
# Count observations by second
counts = df.groupby(level=0).size().reset_index(name='observations')

            timestamp  observations
0 2021-03-05 00:00:00             2
1 2021-03-05 00:02:00             1
2 2021-03-05 00:03:00             1
```

As you may have noticed, this result is missing the timestamp `2021-03-05 00:01:00`. If you want to have all timestamps, you need to declare start time and an end time. For this example, I'll just create 4 minutes.

```py
# Range of 4 minutes
minutes = pd.date_range(start='2021-03-05 00:00:00', periods=4, freq='min')
# Convert to data frame
minutes = pd.DataFrame(minutes, columns=['timestamp'])

            timestamp
0 2021-03-05 00:00:00
1 2021-03-05 00:01:00
2 2021-03-05 00:02:00
3 2021-03-05 00:03:00
```

So all you need to do now is outer join `minutes` and `counts`:

```py
minutes = minutes.merge(counts, on='timestamp', how='outer').fillna(0)

            timestamp  observations
0 2021-03-05 00:00:00           2.0
1 2021-03-05 00:01:00           0.0
2 2021-03-05 00:02:00           1.0
3 2021-03-05 00:03:00           1.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

to_plot = df.resample('T').size()

plt.scatter(to_plot.index, to_plot)
plt.show()
```

**Output**

[image: plot]